# Django; error on printing JSON response in Firefox console

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, django

Urls.py:

```
from .views import get_data

app_name = 'javascript'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('api/data', get_data, name='api-data'),

]
```

Views.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_data(request):                
    dictionary = {'Name':'John'}
    return JsonResponse(dictionary)

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'javascript/index.html')
```

Index.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/api/data/",
    success: function(dictionary){
        console.log(dictionary)
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("errorrr")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
</script>
```

Using AJAX, I want to print dictionary contents upon `index.html` load. However,  the Ajax call fails for some reason. Console.log output is:

```
errorrr
127.0.0.1:8000:30:3
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(), … }
```

Is there any mistake in how my jQuery is written?

Comment: you are getting 'errorrr' because you are telling it to print it with this line `console.log("errorrr")`. The ajax call fails for some reason so it executes the code in the error function, which prints to the console the string "errorrr" and the error data (which is what you specificied in your code with those lines: `error: function(error_data){
        console.log("errorrr")
        console.log(error_data)
    }` )

Comment: Thanks Adam, this much I understand. I am more interested to know why the call fails:)

Comment: True that will probably be more useful. What error code does the ajax call return?

Comment: In the ajax request you are calling `url: "/api/data/"` however the url matching regex doesn't have the last `/` try this: `path('api/data/', get_data, name='api-data'),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the urls.py to this:

```
from .views import get_data

app_name = 'javascript'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('api/data[/]?$', get_data, name='api-data'),

]
```

Your AJAX call is to `'api/data/'` which doesn't match the `path('api/data', get_data, name='api-data')` you had. Now with `'api/data[/]?$'` it will match with or without the last `/`.

Comment: My pleasure ;-)